# How to implement SaxContentHandler from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, sax

Is there a relatively feasable cross-browser way of implementing [nsISaxContentHandler](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/parser/xml/public/nsISAXContentHandler.idl)/[ISaxContentHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925547.aspx) in javascript?

I'm asking because I've always been surprised to see most XmlHttpRequest platforms wait until the response to get fully transmitted. Though it's advisable to keep data fetched over XmlHttpRequests as small as possible, it would be interesting to show each item of a list as soon as it gets in.